# VBA Class Object and Events

Tags: vba, excel

I'm designing a UI with VBA in Excel. I created two classes: bag and map.
They have slightly different properties. My map looks like this:

[image: Application Map]
[image: Application Map Table (directory)]

As you see, it consists of different rectangles. I wrote the following code:

```
endNum = 87

For I = 3 To endNum
Top = Workbooks("Reference").Worksheets("Directory").Cells(I, 3)
Left = Workbooks("Reference").Worksheets("Directory").Cells(I, 4)
Width = Workbooks("Reference").Worksheets("Directory").Cells(I, 5)
Height = Workbooks("Reference").Worksheets("Directory").Cells(I, 6)
ID = Workbooks("Reference").Worksheets("Directory").Cells(I, 7)
Rotation = Workbooks("Reference").Worksheets("Directory").Cells(I, 10)
Name = Workbooks("Reference").Worksheets("Directory").Cells(I, 8)
TypeObj = Workbooks("Reference").Worksheets("Directory").Cells(I, 12)

Set sh = w.Shapes.AddShape(msoShapeRectangle, Left, Top, Width, Height)
    sh.Select
    Selection.ShapeRange.Fill.Visible = msoFalse
    Selection.ShapeRange.Rotation = Rotation
    Selection.ShapeRange.Title = Title
Next I
```

It goes through each row and create the shape and modify its properties. This is great, but the shape class doesn't allow me to add custom properties to its class. Each box has a coordinate x,y,z values in real-world application. After doing some research on OO programming, I decided to create map class and then build my shapes on the screen using those objects (instead of referring to the excel sheet reference table). This is my code for creating map objects:

```
Public Sub MapObjects()

Dim R As Variant
Dim C As Variant
Dim X As Long

With Workbooks("Reference").Worksheets("Directory").UsedRange
    R = .Rows.Count
    C = .Columns.Count
End With

Dim ObjArray(1 To 100) As Map

For X = 1 To UBound(ObjArray)
    Set ObjArray(X) = New Map
Next

For X = 1 To UBound(ObjArray)
    ObjArray(X).MID = Workbooks("Reference").Worksheets("Directory").Cells(X + 1, 1)
    ObjArray(X).MTop = Workbooks("Reference").Worksheets("Directory").Cells(X + 1, 2)
    ObjArray(X).MLeft = Workbooks("Reference").Worksheets("Directory").Cells(X + 1, 3)
    ObjArray(X).MWidth = Workbooks("Reference").Worksheets("Directory").Cells(X + 1, 4)
    ObjArray(X).MHeight = Workbooks("Reference").Worksheets("Directory").Cells(X + 1, 5)
    ObjArray(X).MName = Workbooks("Reference").Worksheets("Directory").Cells(X + 1, 7)
    ObjArray(X).MParent = Workbooks("Reference").Worksheets("Directory").Cells(X + 1, 8)
    ObjArray(X).MRotation = Workbooks("Reference").Worksheets("Directory").Cells(X + 1, 9)
    ObjArray(X).MTitle = Workbooks("Reference").Worksheets("Directory").Cells(X + 1, 10)
Next
```

This code works perfectly, but the objects only last for the time the Sub is being compiled. At the end, they're all gone. I did some googling and found some articles suggesting that I should create my objects outside of the Sub, so I modified my code to this:

```
Option Explicit
Dim ObjArray(1 To 100) As New Map

Public Sub MapObjects()

Dim R As Variant
Dim C As Variant
Dim X As Long

With Workbooks("Reference").Worksheets("Directory").UsedRange
    R = .Rows.Count
    C = .Columns.Count
End With

For X = 1 To UBound(ObjArray)
    ObjArray(X).MID = Workbooks("Reference").Worksheets("Directory").Cells(X + 1, 1)
    ObjArray(X).MTop = Workbooks("Reference").Worksheets("Directory").Cells(X + 1, 2)
    ObjArray(X).MLeft = Workbooks("Reference").Worksheets("Directory").Cells(X + 1, 3)
    ObjArray(X).MWidth = Workbooks("Reference").Worksheets("Directory").Cells(X + 1, 4)
    ObjArray(X).MHeight = Workbooks("Reference").Worksheets("Directory").Cells(X + 1, 5)
    ObjArray(X).MName = Workbooks("Reference").Worksheets("Directory").Cells(X + 1, 7)
    ObjArray(X).MParent = Workbooks("Reference").Worksheets("Directory").Cells(X + 1, 8)
    ObjArray(X).MRotation = Workbooks("Reference").Worksheets("Directory").Cells(X + 1, 9)
    ObjArray(X).MTitle = Workbooks("Reference").Worksheets("Directory").Cells(X + 1, 10)
Next
```

Unfortunately, the code compiled, but nothing changed. Alright. **Here are my questions**:

1. In the first code, is there a way I can make a Map class array with a modular size. I don't want it to be 0 to 100 and that's why I have the R variable to tell me how many objects I initially had in my directory. However, when I change 100 to R or (R-1), it gives me an error saying that it must be a constant.
2. Is there a way I can have permanent class objects? I'd like them to be saved in memory after I save the workbook or at least saved until the WB is open.
3. The map objects won't move much, but it's a possibility that user will re-arrange them. In case of bag objects, the application will distribute them automatically and place them onto the map objects if their type matches (e.g. same dimension). However, this is not the end of the game. The user will re-arrange them and perhaps create new shapes (I think I can find a solution to this challenge down the road). Assuming I can solve #2, I'd like to be able to update the shape's location (Top & Left) properties every time the user moves them around. If that's not possible, create a button to update the properties of each map object at once (by going thru. a for loop...). Though this way is fine with me, is there a better way of doing it?

Sorry for making this so complicated and I really really really appreciate your time and patience. If this question has already been asked, forgive me. I'm illiterate in programming. This is my second VBA programming assignment.

Comment: Regarding point #2, ...you seem to misunderstand the concept of *scoping*. Declare your object variable at module level in a standard module, and it will "live" for as long as `ThisWorkbook` is open. Point #1 could have been illustrated with a 2-liner [mcve] and the answer is on this site: `Dim` statements aren't executable, if you need a dynamically allocated array use the `ReDim` keyword, which *is* executable. #3 is too broad for this site, and since the code doesn't do what you need it to do it's also off-topic on [codereview.se], which would otherwise be the place for "a better way".